# Big pandas dataframe management

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need your help in order to manage a pandas df (ca. 30 mln rows). In particular, I need extract data from the df and create some sheets (that I will export in csv) with a specific form.
In my df I have 4 variables (country, partners, years, product), and for each country and product I need a df with partners (in column) and years (in row).
These are my variables:

```
country = "ITA"
years = [2017, 2018]
product = 3312
partners = ["FRA", "USA", "CHI"]
```

Data that I have to extract are in column "Value" of df. I made a code that is really slow that create a dataframe "sheet" with what I need:

```
sheet=pd.DataFrame({"Partners" : partners})      
    for n in years:
        association = []
        for i in partners:
            association.append(round(df.loc[(df['Reporter'] == country) & (df['Partner'] == i) & (df['Year'] == n) & (df['Product'] == product), 'Value'].sum()/10**6 , 3)) # data are in bln
        sheet[n] = association
```

Pls, help me with an optimized code to do this operation.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your expected output.

Comment: please show expected output

Comment: I have solved directly with pivot table.. thanks for ur support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .loc operator will be very fast and is simple to implement, especially compared to the loop you are proposing:

```
sheet_subset = sheet.loc[(sheet['country']=="ITA") & (sheet['years'].isin([2017,2018])) & (sheet['product']==3312) & (sheet['partners'].isin(["FRA", "USA", "CHI"]))]
```